# Is it possible to get EPIPE from write() to a file descriptor on an NFS disk?

Tags: c++, centos, nfs, epipe

My C++ application seems to have gotten an `EPIPE` errno result after a failing call to `write()`. The file descriptor passed to `write()` is for a file on an NFS mounted disk.

The man page for `write()` describes `EPIPE` with:

```
fd is connected to a pipe or socket whose reading end is closed.  When this
happens the writing process will also receive a SIGPIPE signal.  (Thus, the write
return value is seen only if the program catches, blocks or ignores this signal.)
```

So I am confused as to how I would get `EPIPE`.  Could it be that this is a multi-threading issue and the errno is incorrectly being supplied for a different thread?  I thought errno is thread safe, so that seems unlikely, but then getting EPIPE seems to make no sense.  This is on Centos v4.

Comment: Is it possible that a FIFO was created at that location?

Comment: Remember that NFS is implemented using sockets, so it's most likely that the NFS server closed the connection, and the NFS layer passes that error on to you.

Comment: @Kevin It is not a FIFO, just a regular file.